# Threading and Recursion in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, recursion

I have this function which takes a path and searches for a file in it. I have two approaches: one is to make the main thread do the job, and the another is to make a worker thread do the job. When the main thread does the job it returns all the files but when a worker thread does the job it returns only a small number of the files in that path only. It doesn't do the recursion step which enters sub-directories. Here is the code:

```
public void  GetAllFiles(string sdir)
        {

                foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(sdir))
                {

                    try
                    {
                        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*"))
                        {
                            string filename = Path.GetFileName(file);

                            listView1.Items.Add(filename);

                        }
                        GetAllFiles(dir);
                    }
                    catch (Exception error)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
```

and here is how i call the thread:

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(() => GetAllFiles("C:\\Users\\modz\\Desktop\\games"));
 thread.Start();
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @ScottHunter i need to know what causes this but i think it is the recursion

Comment: I suspect that you are getting an error message. This is because you are trying to add the items to a ListView object. This is not valid on any thread other than the thread the ListView was created on. Have you checked to see if any errors are written to the console?

Comment: how stupid i am @JeremyWest you are right the error is because the listview but could you tell me how to send the result back to the main tread  ?

Comment: Generally, you would want to have a function that accumulates the results into a List or something and then have the main thread populate the items into the list. Or you can use databinding to bind to the list.

If you are using the latest version of C# you could use the `await` mechanism.

Comment: Don't traverse the filesystem yourself; The `Directory` class has methods for getting all files in the directory at any depth.  Just use that.

Comment: Yes, @Servy 's suggestion is certainly the simplest approach.

Comment: @servy It always gives me errors in access files that cant be read or with high lvl premission

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails when run on a background thread because you are trying to modify a control from a thread other than the GUI thread, which is not allowed. To fix this, you must accumulate the results into some kind of collection on the background thread and then populate the list view from the main thread.

However, there is a built-in function that accomplishes what you want. So the simplest and likely best solution is the following:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var file in files) {
  listView1.Items.Add(file);
}
```

If you want to do it manually, you can still use your method with some modification, such as:

```
public void GetAllFiles(string sdir, List<string> files) {
  foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(sdir)) {
    try {
      foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*")) {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(file);
        files.Add(filename);
      }
      GetAllFiles(dir, files);
    } catch (Exception error) {
      Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
    }
  }
}
```

You can then call this synchronously like this:

```
var files = new List<string>();
GetAllFiles(path, files);
foreach (var file in files) {
  listView1.Items.Add(file);
}
```

In the asynchronous case, you need to wait for the background thread to fill the list before the main thread populates the list view. Using tasks and the `async` and `await` keywords is pretty simple.

```
public async void Populate() {
  const string path = ...
  var files = new List<string>();
  await Task.Run(() => GetAllFiles(path, files));
  foreach (var file in files) {
    listView1.Items.Add(file);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer.  You might want to say something about why OP's threading scenario was failing.

Comment: Oh, I did in a comment, but it might not be obvious to readers. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: lol, you know I just realised you wrote the comment up top. (I was about to say _"See such-and-such's comment up top"_.  My bad :)

Comment: It's probably worth having it in the response. You won't be the only person who doesn't see it and is somewhat confused as to why this is the solution .

Answer (score 1):

Your problem with the existing code is you are updating a UI element from a non-UI thread. You can certainly collect your data on a background thread, but you must marshall the data back to the UI before adding to your list view.

To do this you should make your life simple and use a framework that avoids you needing to roll your own threads.

I would suggest using TPL, `await`/`async`, or Microsoft's Reactive Framework. My choice is that latter.

First define an observable to query all of the files:

```
public IObservable<string> GetAllFiles(string sdir)
{
    return
        from dir in Directory.GetDirectories(sdir).ToObservable(Scheduler.Default)
        from file in Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*").ToObservable(Scheduler.Default)
            .Concat(GetAllFiles(dir))
        select file;
}
```

Note that this method is recursive and uses background threads (via `Scheduler.Default`) to do the work.

Now you need to consume it

```
GetAllFiles("C:\\Users\\modz\\Desktop\\games")
    .ObserveOn(listView1)
    .Subscribe(filename => listView1.Items.Add(filename));
```

The `.ObserveOn(listView1)` does all of the marshalling back to the UI thread. The `listView1` parameter can be any UI form or control.

The `.Subscribe(...)` just takes all of the file names and does the add on to the list view.

This code should be very easy to use. Just NuGet `Rx-WinForms` or `Rx-WPF` to get started.